# Is it possible to write arrays inside html script Using angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my HTML code

```
 <script>
    Raven.config('___PUBLIC_DSN___', {
        release: '1.3.0',
        whitelistUrls: {{urls}},
    }).install()
</script>
```

controller code

```
$scope.urls = ['https://test1.com/', 'https://test2.com'];
```

I am getting an error like:

```
SyntaxError: expected property name, got '{'
```

Is it possible OR I do some mistakes in the code? Please suggest/help.

Comment: (_Not sure what Raven it, but_) have you tried simply using `whitelistUrls: urls,`. `{{ ... }}` are used to render the content in HTML, not in the scripts (that's for JavaScript code and its execution)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I tried but it returns an undefined error.

Comment: that's a good sign, it's no longer a SyntaxError, so something else went wrong. Try to resolve that problem next

Comment: Will try. Thanks for giving valuable time. Have a great day.

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You wanted to get solution to a problem, so you implemented a solution. That solution doesn't work correctly, so you want help in troubleshooting the solution. Rather, it's better to ask the root problem here, that way experts will be able to help you better. VTCing as unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize raven inside your AngularJS application if you want to use that `$scope.urls` param. **It's not possible in the way you tried**:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.urls = ['https://test1.com/', 'https://test2.com'];

    Raven.config('___PUBLIC_DSN___', {
        release: '1.3.0',
        whitelistUrls: $scope.urls,
    }).install()
});
```

---

### Append script solution:

You could also try to append this script dynamically to your DOM by using a directive like in this **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54eL0ef2/)**:

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <span>Right after here:</span>
  <div my-append-script url-data="urls"></div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.urls = ['https://test1.com/', 'https://test2.com'];
});

myApp.directive('myAppendScript', function () {
    return {
      restrit: 'A',
      scope: {
        urlData: '=urlData'
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var wrapArray = '';

        angular.forEach(scope.urlData, function (item, index) {
           if (index !== 0 ) {
              wrapArray += ','+"'"+item+"'";
           } else {
              wrapArray += "'"+item+"'";
           }
        });

        wrapArray = '['+wrapArray+']';  
        var script = document.createElement('script');

        script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        script.innerHTML = `
        console.log(`+wrapArray+`);
        Raven.config('___PUBLIC_DSN___', {
            release: '1.3.0',
            whitelistUrls: `+wrapArray+`,
        }).install()`;

        element.append(script);
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: yes. This works but according to my code structure, I must implement in <script> tag. Thanks.

Comment: @lin that's not a complete solution. OP wanted to extract scoped variables from the app to the script

Comment: @AlekseySolovey feal free to add an other answer.

Comment: My problem is still not solved. How Can I mark as completed? I want implement inside <script> tag. If you have a solution for that then please suggest.

Comment: @Rock angularjs doesn't share variables outside of scope, consider the solution above wrapped in script: `<script>var myApp = ... </script>`

Comment: @aleksey-solovey I haven't tried. But I will try and get back you if works.

Comment: @Rock, i added an other solution. You can mark an answer as correct by using the "grey hook" near the answer upvote button.